# Is there a way to handle parquet file with INT96 parquet type residing in GCS using Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to load a parquet file with INT96 parquet type residing in GCS to BigQuery using Data Fusion.

Created a pipeline with GCS ad BigQuery component without any Wrangler as Wrangler does not support parquet format.

"MapReduce program 'phase-1' failed with error: MapReduce JobId job_1567423947791_0001 failed. Please check the system logs for more details"

Q.1:- Can we check detailed Map reduce log for this job id ? I know we can do this in Cloudera supported Apache Hadoop.

Q.2:- Failure without wrangler is not only occurring in case of parquet but even in case of plain text file. Does Wrangler is mandatory to have in pipeline ?

Q.3:- When we tried Spark Engine instead of Map Reduce it resulted in showing failure reason as “INT96 not yet implemented”. Any work around to overcome this error ? Parquet file without INT96 field got processed successfully.

Comment: INT96 is a deprecated type that was never implemented in the parquet library that the released plugins are using. However, support has been added in the develop version of the plugins at https://github.com/cdapio/hydrator-plugins. You can try building the plugins, deploying the format-parquet plugin, then re-deploying your pipeline and see if it can read it as a timestamp.

Comment: Thank you very much Albert for your response !!! If I am not wrong, reading parquet with INT96 is not supported in GCP Data Fusion and if we want to read, we have to build and deploy plugin in GCP Data Fusion

Comment: That's correct for now, until the latest develop code is released and Data Fusion updated to use the new code.